# string empty when debugging, correct when used

Tags: c++

I can't see the value of a string if it is being copied (and not passed by reference) in the debugger (both in CLion and plain gdb).

The class I'm using to reproduce this is the following:

```
struct A{
    explicit A(std::string s) {
        std::ifstream in(s, std::ios__base::in); 
        in.close();
    }
}
```

`s` is empty in the debugger throughout the constructor's code, but the ifstream reads its value correctly.

Below two screenshots.

[Debugging on CLion (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zs3lf.png)

[Debugging on CLion (image 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AW2lg.png)

This happens using C++17 and no / all optimizations.

Comment: Do you have any compiler optimisation switches turned on?

Comment: @GrahamS I've tried with both no and all optimizations. (edited the question with this detail)

Comment: Did you clean project after turning optimizations off?

Comment: Try compiling with -O0 -g3

Comment: @FlorinM still nothing. Tried with plain g++ and gdb too